QueryDSL join(a, b) vs join(b).on(): Why does @SQLRestriction behave differently?
Intro:
I'm using QueryDSL with Hibernate in a Spring Boot project. I've noticed a difference in the way @SQLRestriction is applied when using join(a, b) versus join(b).on(). Specifically, when using join(a, b), the @SQLRestriction on both entities a and b is applied, but when using join(b).on(), only the @SQLRestriction on entity a is applied.
Example Entities:
@Entity
@SQLRestriction("deleteTime is null")
data class Order(
    @Id
    val id: Long,

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    val customer: Customer,

    val deleteTime: LocalDateTime?
)

@Entity
@SQLRestriction("deleteTime is null")
data class Customer(
    @Id
    val id: Long,

    val name: String,
    val deleteTime: LocalDateTime?
)

QueryDSL Example:
Using join(a, b):
val query = JPAQuery<Order>(entityManager)
val order = QOrder.order
val customer = QCustomer.customer

query.from(order)
     .join(order.customer, customer)
     .where(customer.name.eq("John Doe"))
     .fetch()

Resulting Native Query:
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.id AND c.delete_time IS NULL
WHERE o.delete_time IS NULL AND c.name = 'John Doe';

Using join(b).on():
val query = JPAQuery<Order>(entityManager)
val order = QOrder.order
val customer = QCustomer.customer

query.from(order)
     .join(customer).on(order.customer.id.eq(customer.id))
     .where(customer.name.eq("John Doe"))
     .fetch()

Resulting Native Query:
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c ON o.customer_id = c.id
WHERE o.delete_time IS NULL AND c.name = 'John Doe';

Note: The resulting native queries are not from actual QueryDSL execution but are written to illustrate the behavior I observed.
Issue:
When using join(a, b), the @SQLRestriction on both Order and Customer entities is applied correctly. However, when using join(b).on(), the @SQLRestriction on the Customer entity is not applied automatically. Interestingly, the @SQLRestriction on the Order entity is still applied correctly in the from clause.
Question:
Why does @SQLRestriction behave differently when using join(b).on() compared to join(a, b)? Is there a way to ensure that @SQLRestriction is applied to both entities when using join(b).on()?
Any insights or documentation references that explain this behavior would be greatly appreciated.
•   In a real service operation, when joining two tables a and b, I noticed that the @SQLRestriction was not applied in the query log.
•   Initially, there was no relationship between the two tables.
•   I observed that the code working correctly in another project had the common point of having relationships between tables.
•   I established the relationship and used join(b).on(), but still only the @SQLRestriction on entity a was applied.
•   When using join(a, b), both restrictions were applied as expected.

